# Running windows task scheduler while logged off

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

On Windows task scheduler, I'm trying to run a task where an SQL query will execute and output(spool) my data to a csv file. running it manually works fine and scheduling it works fine too. However, when I try to run it with the option of "whether user is logged in or not", my task stays at "running" for a long time and does not output my result. What could be the issue and how do I solve it? This is windows 7 pro, and i'm on a work pc (not as an admin or anything).

My event log is 129, if that helps in anyway

Comment: Please explain the logic you are using to create the SQL output file? If this a stored proc executed or called, a directory SQL query you are running from sqlcmd, osql, or mysqld or what? A little clarification of what you're using may be helpful including knowing if the CSV output file is located on a local drive from the machine task scheduler runs it, a mapped drive, a UNC path, or what. Have you also checked the Task Scheduler option `Run with highest privileges`? I'm happy to help with more detail so just hit me back and let me know.